# Sense8 S2E11 plot holes

Tags: plot-explanation, sense8

I started to watch Sense8 recently, knowing that the plot was cut short and concluded in a 2h30 special episode begged by fans, so probably disappointing. But I must admit: I really loved the show. Characters, storylines, topics, ... Everything was so enjoyable ... well... until S2E11 (which, AFAIK was written as a season finale, not the series finale).

Seriously, I can't understand how a well-written show suddenly can be that botched. Let me explain:

From the beginning, it didn't go well with one of the most annoying cliché in movies/shows:

> "Mwhahaha I finally have my long awaited revenge and despite I'm chased by half of Seoul's police force, i'm slowly coming to my prey to put the final blow and.... errr... Finally no, all things considered I rather sparing his life, being captured and sent back to jail where I'll face certain death."

But that was not too bad compared to the incomprehensible mess which comes afterwards:

> 1. Where does Puck come from and how does he know Sun needs an escape plan right here, right now? 
>
>
>  2. How can Kara cook full boxes of blockers in a few minutes while her whole cluster (including her) didn't understand how to make one minutes before?
>
>
>  3. How can she fly from India to France with 4+ boxes of blockers and have airport security or customs not notice them?
>
>
>  4. Where has Sun found her false passport and how can the airport cop not recognize Korea's most wanted fugitive, who did not even change her haircut?
>
>
>  5. How does Will know the location of BPO secret base in London and how does he sneak into the meeting room to trick Whispers?
>
>
>  6. How does the rest of the cluster know where Jonas is living?
>
>
>  7. Assuming they obviously have no trouble walking in BPO's base, why do they kidnap Whispers to exchange him with Wolfgang instead of killing Whispers and sneak Wolfgang out, hence definitely solving their problems?

**Did I miss major explanations** or is this episode definitely filled with plot holes that litteraly kill the story? The thing is I've been looking for reviews on the internet and no one seems to be disappointed as I am, so **please help me fill the holes !** :)

Comment: I haven't watched it yet to know if any of these are answered, but I do wonder if they created cliff hangers, because they are still hoping to continue the work on another medium? I know a lot of people feel it would make a good comic book series. The following website also contemplates another comeback: https://www.hypable.com/sense8-future-seasons-revival/

Comment: Regardless, you have multiple questions here which makes this **too broad**.

Comment: I read the guidelines and fail to see how my question is too broad. Basically it is : "I noticed these plot holes, is there any actual explanation ?". Should I write one question per plot hole ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ideally, yes, one question at a time.